# Rails-spree : Product images disappearing when updating images

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

There are images for each product shown on each respective product page.  Now, I need to change the images for some products. In that case, either the earlier images are disappearing and new images are not showing or the images are getting duplicated.

What I am doing is, I upload the images to a S3 bucket via python program and make them public, and then it runs a `rake images:some_method_name` task, the method (in the model) accesses `AWS::S3 bucket` where images are, it creates a Tempfile object and writes the image files into it as objects.

It destroys earlier images-links for that product, and it starts to create new image-links for the product images, but when trying to '....save!', there it's giving some access denied issues.

> ```
> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /i
> from ~/.rvm/rubies/........../fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir'.
> ```

What may I be missing/doing wrong?